# What's "feedback" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

What's *feedback* in Esperanto? I used *respondo* (for example, *biologia respondo* for *biofeedback*), but I think it may not be the best translation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Feedback* has several meanings in English.

In science and engineering, a circuit providing feedback is a ***retrokuplo***, and the result can be *pozitiva/negativa retrokuplado* or *-eco*. (*Kupli* is to couple.) Biological feedback is *biologia **retroregulig(ad)o***, the process by which a system is steadily regulated *(reguligata)*. [The first is in Wells's; both are in PIV.]

- *Aŭdiĝis terura retrokupla kriĉo.* There was heard a terrible screech of feedback.
- *En la korpo, homeostato estas la celo de retroreguligado per multaj retroagaj reakcioj.* In the body, homeostasis is the goal of a feedback process using many compensatory reactions.

More generally, it is *re-enmetado* or ***rea enmetado***.

- *Ĝi estis ree enmetita en la sistemon.* It was fed back into the system.

The word is also used to mean "comments and criticism in reaction to a proposal or published work" which could be translated as ***priaj reagoj*** or something similar.

- *Mi ricevis komentojn kaj kritikojn pri la propono.* I received comments and criticisms about the proposal.
- *Ŝi legis la malneton kaj donis reagajn konsilojn.* She read the draft and gave some feedback.

Answer (score 4):

> Retrokuplo - Funkciado de sistemo kies eligo estas retrokuplita kun la enigo; la signalo tiel transigata: pozitiva, negativa retrokuplo. http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/retrokupl.html#retrokupl.0o