# How do you say "feedback loop" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

The proposal is "resonigaj lopoj", but I'm looking for something that goes beyond the "loop" translation and focuses on the process. I was thinking of just using "retroreguligo", which is part of [this answer about feedback](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/2381/134). 
Here's the complete sentence: "But those numbers do not include tipping points, most feedback loops, additional warming hidden by toxic air pollution or the aspects of equity and climate justice. "

The Swedish word is "återkopplingseffekter", retrokuplaj efikoj. 
Another proposal is "memnutraj spiraloj".

Comment: "resonigaj" seems to be about resonance (audio, social or otherwise). While feedback (or a "feedback loop") can lead to resonance effects, it doesn't necessarily have to. (Depends, among other factors, on the damping of the system.) Resonance between a microphone and loudspeaker(s) is colloquially (and probably also in stage tech jargon) called "feedback" in English, but audio doesn't seem to be what your sentence is about, so I'd avoid that adjective there.

Comment: Maybe you can draw some inspiration for a translation from https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermitcikla_regilo

Answer (score 3):

Maybe *[retrokuplo](http://www.simplavortaro.org/vorto/retrokuplo)* will work. It's also [used in the Vikipedio article](https://eo.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Fermitcikla_regilo&oldid=5696649) "Fermitcikla regilo".

Comment: A lot of people don't like "retrokuplo" for feedback. (I like it!) But that way it's just another way of saying feedback, and I'd like something focusing on the process, not just "feedback". Thank you!

Comment: Hmm ... "retrokuplado", then? 

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "resonigado"? The loop-part is probably accurately described with the -ad- suffix.

Comment: But resonigado focuses on sound, and that’s not the type of feedback loop I’m looking for. It’s climate change related.

Comment: Why wouldn't it work though? I think the meaning remains relevant.

Answer (score 0):

*memefiko* rilatas la "buklan" efikon de io sur la sama afero. La ekzemplo vortara (PIV) estas elektronika sed la signifo estas pli ampleksa. Temas pri io, kio efikas sur si mem. Mi tradukus tion, en tiu kunteksto jene:

memefikaj cikloj